# GStreamer record iradio-mode artifacts

Tags: audio-streaming, audio-recording, gstreamer

I'm trying to record internet radio while listen it. I use the following line, but comes to my attention that when I set the iradio-mode true some noises comes in the recorded file, not in the playback. Without iradio-mode, all is ok. But in my app I need this mode to get the title message.

```
gst-launch souphttpsrc location="<radio channel>" iradio-mode=true ! tee name=t ! queue ! decodebin2 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! osxaudiosink  t. ! queue ! filesink location=rectest.mp3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:
Now I use icydemux, after that the sound comes crystal clear.